# Automatically not allow tag for certain friend

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos, facebook-tags, facebook-privacy

I have an overzealous friend on Facebook who always takes random pictures and tags me in them. Is there an automatic way to prevent having him tag me?

If I am actually in a picture, is there a way to force him to take it down, for example can it be reported to Facebook and they take it down for him?

It's kind of out of control - like 100 pictures all at once so it's hard to go to each to untag myself.

Comment: @pnuts I believe I do have that setting enabled, but it doesn't prevent him from saying the photo was with me. For example even if I wasn't tag in a photo, it may say "with Celeritas".